# Mysql - backup partial data

Tags: mysql, backup, partial

Is there an easy way to backup and restore partial data from a mysql database while maintaining the FK constraints?

Say if I have 2 tables

```
| CustomerId | CustomerName |
-----------------------------
| 12         | Bon Jovi     |
| 13         | Seal         |
```

and

```
| AddressId| CustomerId     | City    |
---------------------------------------
| 1        | 12             | London  |
| 2        | 13             | Paris   |
```

The backup would only take customer 12 and address 1.

My goal is to take a large database from a production server and replicate it locally, but with partial data.

Due to fairly complicated schema, a custom query is not an option. Also I can't rely on the existence of a main table from which one would get the related rows.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could replicate specific customers manually and by adding an FK constraint on the *address* table replication  will fail to insert/update these records.
For replicating specified tables in the db http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-do-table .
Use this parameter to silently skip errors on replication http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-slave.html#sysvar_slave_skip_errors .